# How can I change the class of input elements in a certain division

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have input fields within divs with the class of "next" as this :

```
<div id="Q1">    
    <input class="next" type="radio" id="listIt_YN_UA" name="listIt_YN" value="U">&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <label for="listIt_YN_UA"><span class="red">Come Back To This Question At A Later Time</span></label><br /><br />
</div>
```

Then the following function :

```
function answerQ(value) {
    var tab_pool = ["Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4", "Q5", "Q6", "Q7", "Q8", "Q9", "Q10", "Q11", "Q12"];
    var visible = $(".tab:visible").attr('class').split(" ")[1];
    var curr_ind = $.inArray(visible, tab_pool);
    var returnTo = value;
    $(".tab:visible").hide();
    curr_ind = curr_ind - returnTo;
    $("." + tab_pool[curr_ind]).show();
    document.getElementById(tab_pool[curr_ind]).checked=false;
    $(".finished").hide();
    $(".next").show();
}
```

I am trying to change the "next" class in the current visible div with a statement inside the above function. I have tried a couple of things such as the one below but none are working. Any ideas?

```
$("." + tab_pool[curr_ind]).removeClass("next").addClass("newNext");
```

Comment: Where are the elements with `class="Q1"`, `class="Q2"`, etc. in your HTML?

Comment: @Barmar That is not class it is div id

Comment: Then why are you putting `.` before it in the jQuery selector? Use `#` for ID, `.` for class.

Comment: and how does `$(".tab:visible")` relate to your html you provided.  I don't think this function relates to the html you are using at all.

Comment: @Barmar tried id with #,  tried (.next) nothing works. The function itself works just cant seem to change class of inputs

Comment: Did you try my answer below?

Comment: @Barmar YES tried id with #, tried (.next) nothing works. The function itself works just cant seem to change class of inputs

Comment: Please make a jsfiddle with your current code.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('#'+tab_pool[curr_ind]).find('input').removeClass('next').addClass('newNext');
```

You need to use `#` rather than `.` before the `tab_pool` ID, and then use `.find('input')` to get to the input element.

Comment: tried it, no good! also tried $('.'+tab_pool[curr_ind]).find('input').removeClass('next').addClass('newNext');

Comment: I asked you above to make a fiddle showing your current code. It's impossible to know what you're doing wrong without seeing the code.

Comment: It would be easier if I gave you a link to the page and explained a bit of what is going on

Comment: OK, give me the link to the real page while you're working on it.

Answer (score 0):

Let me show the code for the div with id:`Q1` in particular-

```
$(".next").click(function toggle(){
    if($("#" + "Q1" + ">input[type=radio]").attr('checked')==undefined)
    {
     $("input[type=radio]").attr('checked', true);
     $("input[type=radio]").removeClass("next").addClass("newNext");
    }
    else
    {
     $("input[type=radio]").removeAttr('checked');
     $("input[type=radio]").removeClass("newNext").addClass("next");
    }
})
```

So basically the jquery object in case of your implementation will be

```
$("#" + tab_pool[curr_ind] + ">input[type=radio]")
```

Check this **[fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HWj6m/1/)**